# Jasmine unit test failing with resolve values in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

Before i started, i have followed the advice found here without any success: [How can I test a controller with resolve properties in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322155/how-can-i-test-a-controller-with-resolve-properties-in-angularjs)

Im my app.js, i have a simple resolve:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

    .state('index', {
        url: '/index',
        templateUrl: 'html/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        resolve: {
            homeInfo:  function() {
                return {
                    subtitle : 'Welcome to tables, ladders and chairs'
                };
            }
        }
    })
```

And in my HomeController.js:

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, srv1, srv2, homeInfo, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.$broadcast('brdSubtitle', homeInfo.subtitle);

});
```

My test:

```
describe('HomeController', function () {

    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller, homeController;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;

        homeController = $controller('HomeController', {'$rootScope': $rootScope, '$scope': $scope, homeInfo: { subtitle : 'Welcome to tables, ladders and chairs' }});
    }));

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(homeController).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have a subtitle', function() {
        expect(homeController.homeInfo.subtitle.text()).toBe('Welcome to tables, ladders and chairs');
    });
});
```

Error is:

```
TypeError: homeController.homeInfo is undefined in /path/to/specs.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you didn't do `this.homeInfo = homeInfo;` in controller, and `homeController.homeInfo` should be undefined in this case.

There's no reason why mocked `homeInfo` local dependency should be tested. Test what happens in controller instead:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
    ...

    brdSubtitleListener = jasmine.createSpy('brdSubtitleListener');
    $scope.$on('brdSubtitle', brdSubtitleListener);

    homeController = $controller('HomeController', {'$rootScope': $rootScope, '$scope': $scope, homeInfo: { subtitle : 'Welcome to tables, ladders and chairs' }});
}));


it('should broadcast a subtitle', function() {           
  expect(brdSubtitleListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Object), 'Welcome to tables, ladders and chairs');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to mock the service value in a `beforeEach`, because apparently putting the value in the `$controller` parameter does not work.

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('homeInfo', {
        subtitle : 'Welcome to tables, ladders and chairs'
    });
}));
```